# How do i return multiple routes from one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to do something like

```
const RoutesList = () => (
   <Fragment>
     <Route .../>
     <Route .../>
     <Route .../>
   </Fragment>
)
```

and use this inside `Routes`

```
...
<Routes>
   <RoutesList/>
</Routes>
...
```

but it throws error saying `Uncaught Error: [PreBuiltRoutes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`
Even though i am returning Fragment.

Comment: Have you tried returning an array of routes instead of a fragment, then using spread operator ?

Comment: seems pretty clear to me: `All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`. Your child is neither of these but a component called `RoutesList`.

Comment: @RiadhAdrani i did try, the same error, even if i return Route directly

Comment: @RobinZigmond does that mean it is not possible to do what i am doing ? and how about custom protected routes they seem to work

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with React Router, but it seems that it's indeed not possible. I don't see much - or any - gain in having a custom component which is just a bunch of `Route`s wrapped in a Fragment.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the thing is we need to provide the user of the package component which would return list of routes, and he is the one putting them as <Routes> children

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow - but it sounds like returning an array as @RiadhAdrani suggests might be the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround (Edit)

Actually, you can execute `RoutesList` as a function, but do not use hooks within.

```js
<Routes>{RoutesList()}</Routes>
```

---

The problem is that `<RoutesList>` is considered by react-router as any other component, but it expect an array of `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`.

I suggest 2 methods at the moment:

### Exporting an Array

Using react-router-dom v6, you can do this in `Routes.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default [
  <Route .../>,
  <Route .../>,
  <Route .../>
];
```

then, use it like this:

```js
import Routes from "./Routes"

...
<Routes>...[{routes}]</Routes>
...
```

### Exporting React.Fragment directly

Also, you can export a fragment:

```js
export const RoutesAsFragment = (
  <>
    <Route ...>
    <Route ...>
    <Route ...>
  </>
);
```

and use them as an object:

```js
<Routes>{RoutesAsFragment}</Routes>
```

here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-8kzh08?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: yeah this works, but our package has to export react component with list of routes, not an array

Comment: @howardwolowitz you need the routes to be dynamically created or, are they a set of fixed ones ? The problem now is, when you use a functional component `RoutesList`, what will be returned is a standard component <RoutesList> that will wrap `<React.Fragment>`. You can export a Fragment as const if your routes are not dynamically created.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation of how your approach does not work at the moment.

Comment: they are created from data from another class that hold information about the pages

Comment: @howardwolowitz if you read your question this given answer already answered it. But you keep adding informations in the comments at which point your original question and your question in the comments won't match.

Comment: @howardwolowitz another update to my answer which is the closest to what you want to achieve.